# Получить строку по адресу в памяти

Tags: указатели, delphi, память

Есть адрес в памяти (хранится в переменной `adr:integer`);
по адресу хранится целое число 4б. 
Задача получить строку.

Как реализовать?

```
Var
  Ard:integer;
  s:string;
begin
  s:=IntToStr(Integer(Adr));//Верно ли?
end;
```

Comment: > Есть адрес в памяти(хранится в переменной adr:integer)  

прочел несколько раз, думал, что у меня в глазах глюки. Аннет - адрес в целочисленной переменной. Зачем, если есть типизированный указатель?

Comment: В коментарии отвечено) переменная не моя, и читать мне ее нужно из приатаченой к чужому процессу длл, точнее там цепочки адресов. которые передаются из основной программы(уже моей). и дабы не использовать ReadProccessMemory дабы нахожусь я в одном адресном пространстве с процессом, очень хочется использовать указатели, а их тип менее важен будь то типизированый указатель или нет. главное суть работы с оными) но собственно @KoVadim уже это прояснил, осталось проэксперементировать и понять как сие будет работать)

Comment: я просто написал это до того, как вы пояснили свой вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно в целочисленной переменной хранить адрес. Адреса нужно хранить в указателях. Но если уж так, то тогда `s:=IntToStr(PInteger(Adr)^);` Где `type PInteger = ^Integer;`

Но это плохо. Не известно, что по адресу будет, поэтому результат может быть не сильно предсказуемый.

Comment: Проблема в том что этот код работает в чужом приложении :) отсюда и необходимость работать с адресами как с целочисленными данными.

или я не прав и адреса можно складывать\вычитать\умножать и можно обойтись без целочисленных типов?) хотя после таких манипуляций адреса станут обычными целочисленными типами что не изменит ничего по большому счету)

Comment: адреса можно вычитать друг с дружки, можно адрес увеличивать на какое -то число (или уменьшить). А вот умножения адресов или складывание двух адресов лишено практического смысла.

Comment: Хм, не знал что к адресам можно прибавлять числа...) тогда попутный вопрос... каким образом задать адрес указателя?
    
    Var
      adr: pointer;
    Begin
      adr:= $400000; << компилятор ругается

    Var
      adr:PInteger;
    Begin
      adr:=$40000; Так не проверял пока что, но были подозрения что установится не адрес а значение :)

      adr:=@$400000; и такая идея была но неуверен что игнорирование типов тут поможет)

Comment: >> adr:= $400000; << компилятор ругается

конечно ругается. Присваиваете неприсваеваемое. Нужно компилятору намекнуть

adr:= Pointer($400000);

> @$400000

у константы нет адреса.